# How to update document on pre or post query hook in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, hook

I am trying to update a field on a query hook. For example:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  queryCount: {type: Number, default:0}
});
```

I want to increment and update `queryCount` field on each `find` or `findOne` query.

```
mySchema.post('find', function (doc) {
  // here is the magic
});
```

I have tried a few things but no success so far. Can I achieve this in model or do I have to do it in the controller?

Comment: What have you tried? `doc.update({$inc: {queryCount: 1}}, callback)` doesn't work?

Comment: @JasonCust That's what the OP is asking, whether the same can be done on at the model level. This query will have to be run on the controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is a [post **`init`** hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

```
mySchema.post('init', function (doc) {
  doc.queryCount++;
  doc.save();
});
```

Comment: The link doesn't seem to be working. Could you explain the init hook, in terms of when it is called?

Comment: ["Called internally after a document is returned from mongodb"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-init) (which is what happens in a find query)

Comment: Beware of ParallelSaveError when using this approach in Mongoose 5

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use a mongoose static method which internally calls `findAndUpdate()`

```
mySchema.statics.findWithIncrement = function (query, callback) {

    this.findAndUpdate(query, { $inc: { queryCount: 1 })
        .exec(function(err, res) {

            if (err) return callback(err);

            //Handle response
        });
}
```

And then use the method in your controllers:

```
MyModel.findWithIncrement({name: "someName"}, function (err, result) {

})
```

Comment: I was trying to do it with hooks. I'd accept this if I didn't see @laggingreflex's answer. But still, thank you...

Comment: This is just an alternative... I have already voted up @laggingreflex's answer :)